# Crawl Anywhere+Solr+ Tomcat: not able to access the crawler administration

Tags: solr, tomcat7, web-crawler, solrj

**Question Update:** Thank you Okke Klein for your update.

I am trying to implement crawl anywhere for crawling the doc file folder.

I followed the instruction specified in http://www.crawl-anywhere.com/installation-v300/

Installed tomcat and Apache web server.

so i am trying to login to crawler using :: http///crawler.

but i am getting message as

> The requested URL /crawler was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.0.64 (Win32) Server at localhost Port 80

And for ://ip:8180/crawlerws it giving :

```
<error>
<errno>1</errno>
<errmsg>Missing action</errmsg>
</error>
```

Can any one tell what i am missing and how i can log in to crawler administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crawler admin isn't run under Tomcat. It is run under Apache.

It also seems like your Solr isn't running. This is however not needed for Admin interface.

The crawlerws is running fine looking at response. This is only used however for some interactions in the admin interface and is not crucial.

So reread the portion of Apache setup to get the Admin interface running. It might already be running under `http://ip:80/crawler`.

Comment: yes ..
i solved that solr problm.. the war file i was using was incorrect..
is there another way to crawl files without web server and admin control...in website link they ask to login first and start crawling

Comment: You don't need the admin control to crawl. But it is easier for configuration of rules.

Comment: right now i dont have web server installed..i want to crawl this files..can you guide me for this
is there any document available for this. crawl without crawler admin

Comment: Installing a web server is a lot easier then trying to run CA without one. Especially for the advanced options, that can't be configured in the configuration files.

Comment: i installed web server but still i am not able to open crawler...
changes made “install/crawler/apache/httpd_crawler.conf” file .
do we need to make any changes in apache web server http.conf file also?

Comment: apache log stack:(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Failed to open the Apache2 Service